# Random number generator giving me 0 on a range of 1-20

Tags: javascript

I've asked about a number generator before , and for a while I thought it was operating properly. I come to you today because the latter is not the case. For some reason my code for a number generator is giving me a 0 when the range is supposed to be from 1-20. I'm using javascript and html.

The javascript code:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
```

It worked well for sometime, but now it's breaking my code because of divide by 0 error. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: More code snippet

```
function questionGen()
{
    min = document.getElementById("low").value;
    max = document.getElementById("high").value;
    rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    //Chooses which Math Symbol to use
    switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1)
    {
        case 1:
            if (document.getElementById("addcheck").checked == true)
            {

                answer = add(rand1, rand2);
                break;
            } //end if
        case 2:
            if (document.getElementById("subcheck").checked == true)
            {

                answer = sub(rand1, rand2);
                break;
            } //end if
        case 3:
            if (document.getElementById("mulcheck").checked == true)
            {

                answer = multiply(rand1, rand2);
                break;
            } //end if
        case 4:
            if (document.getElementById("divcheck").checked == true)
            { //Division Checked
                answer = division(rand1, rand2);
                break;
            } //end if
} //end switch
} //end questionGen
```

Outside of this method the variables are created

```
var min;
var max;
```

My division method my get a little hard to follow because of other factors. I still get zeroes in my add, sub, and multiply methods as well.

Add Method

```
function add()
{
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = arguments[0] + " + " + arguments[1];
    answer = arguments[0] + arguments[1];
    document.getElementById("desc24").innerHTML = arguments[0] + " plus " + arguments[1];
    return answer;
} //end add
```

I know the division by 0 is 100% the problem. I have a console.log() to output my second random variable right before division ,and right before it crashes it pops 0 into my console window. The questionGen is the only place I get the random numbers.

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1) + 1);` is working fine :(

Comment: Upload full code or snippet having required values of `max`, `min`

Comment: `it's breaking my code because of  divide by 0 error` :: the equation you've posted does not have a division.

Comment: I get no issues https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sLxzxdbw/

Comment: It looks to me like OP has misidentified the source of his problem.

Comment: @EdHeal that's why you create a random number between 0 and 19 inclusive, and add 1.

Comment: try using this `(Number(max) - Number(min) + 1)`

Comment: You're not calling `parseInt` on the `min` and `max` input `.value` properties. That could be it. The error could be in your division function, which you haven't posted (there's not a single division operation in your snippet). It would help if you created a reproducible example, using JSFiddle or a similar tool

Comment: I had that in the beginning but the problem was still there. My input type for both is number.

Comment: I added min++ and that has fixed the divide by zero. I also noticed that my numbers never reached 20 either so I added a max++ as well. I just wish I knew where the problem was, I added parseInt back in but nothing changed from adding that. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
```

Comment: I don't think he did.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion